# SBT Console in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am beginner in Scala. I cant find how to add SBT Console.
I have sbt shell, but in Scala course i see that they have both: SBT Shell and SBT Console, and using the second one. I tried to write "console" in sbt shell, and after "run", but it says:

error: not found: value run.
So I just want to add somehow this SBT Console, to run my program not only from button "run" in Intellij.

And what about SBT? Is it really needed? Or can i dont use it for Scala?

Comment: Open SBT Shell and type `run`.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably confused by "Shell" and "Console" usually being synonyms, but they actually mean different things with sbt.

sbt shell - is, uhm, a shell that sbt gives you when you run it in interactive mode - i.e. when you just run `sbt` from your terminal. This gives you access to other exciting things, such as running the app (with `run` command), inspecting the build (`inspect ...`), running tests (`test`, obviously) and so on.

sbt console - is an interactive REPL (read-evaluate-perform-loop) that gives you *scala* as an interpreter - i.e. you can type in (or paste) some scala code, and it will be immediately compiled and evaluated - outputting the results. Sbt *console* is also available from sbt *shell* - by running `console`.

So, in order to run your program, you have two options (besides the IntelliJ "run" dialog):

1. From your terminal do `sbt run`
2. From your terminal do `sbt`, then wait for sbt to initialize, then in the sbt *shell* do just `run`.

Refer to [sbt docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Running.html) for more details on different ways to run sbt (spoiler: there's also "batch" mode, where you can run `sbt run` from your terminal - and it is exactly the same as `sbt` and then `run`).

[Sbt Reference manual](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html) might also be helpful - specifically it covers the `sbt console` command.

> And what about SBT? Is it really needed? Or can i dont use it for Scala?

It is not mandatory - you can run scala with maven, it's just a [bit more involved to configure](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html). However, if you allow a bit of personal opinion, I'd recommend using sbt with scala projects (and even with Java projects). For one simple reason - the build definition in sbt is essentially just scala code - you can use any language features, third part libraries and even custom code in your build - which sometimes comes very helpful. Compared to maven, I think it's a big step forward, as in maven you define the build using a XML-based "language" defined by the mvn tool and it's plugins - which is much less customizable.

However, `gradle` also has this advantage, so pick the tool that best suits your needs.